# Problemas con una vista, con metodos create() y store()

Tags: laravel-5, controller, vistas

tengo un Controlador para agregar una "Anotacion" a un alumno, el cual recibe "id_alumno", "id_asignatura" y "id_profesor", pero tengo problemas en la vista, ya que solo me muestra el "id" en los campos y por mas que le cambie parametros no me funciona.

[image: vista anotacion]

Este es el Formulario:

```html
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'agregar/anotacion','method'=>'POST')) }}
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">

    <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('id_alumno', 'Alumno') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('id_alumno', $alumno->id, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('id_asignatura', 'Asignatura') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('id_asignatura', $asignatura->id, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                 {!! Form::label('tipo','Tipo')!!}
                 {!! Form::select('tipo', ['' => 'Seleccionar...','Positiva' => 'Positiva', 'Negativa' => 'Negativa'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                 {!! Form::label('descripcion','Descripcion')!!}
                 {!! Form::textarea('descripcion', null,['class' => 'form-control textarea-descripcion']) !!}
             </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar</button>    
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{URL('showalumnosasignatura', $asignatura->id)}}">Cancelar</a>    
         </div>
  </div>
 {{ Form::close() }}
```

Cuando le hago cambios a la variable, por ejemplo $alumno->nombre y $asignatura_nombre, me muestra bien el nombre del alumno y asignatura pero al registrar la anotacion no recibe los "ids" y me manda error la base de datos. Alguien sabe como podria solucionar esto? quiero que me muestre el Rut y el Codigo de la asignatura en el campo y de forma "disabled". Al colocar disabled tampoco me pesca los "ids" de ambos.

Este es mi Controlador :

```
public function agregarAnotacion($id, $idasi)
{   
    $alumno = Alumno::find($id);
    $asignatura = Asignatura::find($idasi);
    return view('agregar/anotacion')->with('alumno',$alumno)->with('asignatura',$asignatura);
}

public function guardarAnotacion(Request $request)
{
    $conducta = new Conducta($request->all());

    $conducta->id_profesor = auth('profesor')->user()->id;

    $conducta->fecha = Carbon::now();
    $conducta->save();

    flash('Anotacion agregada exitosamente!','success');
    return redirect()->route('conductas.index');
}
```

Y mis rutas :

```
Route::get('agregar/anotacion/{id}/{idasi}','AgregarAnotacionController@agregarAnotacion');
Route::post('agregar/anotacion','AgregarAnotacionController@guardarAnotacion');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de `disabled`, que no se envían, podrías usar la propiedad `readonly` en los campos. Esto sería algo como:

```
{!! Form::text('id_alumno', $alumno->id, array(
                                          'class' => 'form-control',
                                          'readonly' => 'readonly'
                                         )) !!}
```

Adicionalmente, para los campos de texto que serán readonly, puedes desplegar el nombre asociado al ID y añadir, en tu plantilla, un input de tipo hidden que contenga el ID. De esa manera enviarás ambas cosas a tu backend.

```
{!! Form::hidden('id_alumno', $alumno->id) !!}
{!! Form::text('nombre_alumno', $alumno->nombre, array(
                                          'class' => 'form-control',
                                          'readonly' => 'readonly'
                                         )) !!}
```

Comment: Gracias man me salvaste :)